# awn - icons from theme?

Tags: icons, awn

In AWN, when you add a launcher, you can choose the icon to include. It gives you a choice - from Theme or from File. (See screenshot.) What I'm wondering is, where do the icons in the Theme choice actually live? Are they individual graphic files that can be used elsewhere, or are they somehow local to AWN?
[image]

I'm particularly interested in the icons that don't attach to actual standalone applications, like the GMail icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are individual files from the chosen icon-Theme. Of course you can use them for any purpose.

Where they live depends on the chosen icon-theme.

Example:

/usr/share/icons/AwOken/clear/128x128/apps/gmail.png

This is an Icon of the Theme "AwOken" in the size 128x128 pixel. The application-Icon are found in the subfoilder "apps" of each theme.

If you have installed an individual icon-theme (not root) the icons are saved in your home-directory (hidden sub-folder ".icons").

Example: 
/home/michael/.icons/elementary/apps/128/gmail.png

An icon theme can point to another icon theme for all the icons it doesn't support itself. Therefor each icon them has an initial-file called "icon.theme". The row starting with "Inherits" points to the other icons-themes, that should be used in case of a missing icon.

Example:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=elementary
Comment=Smooth modern theme designed to be intuitive.
Inherits=gnome,ubuntu-mono-light,hicolor,gnome-colors-brave

Example=directory-x-normal

#Directory list
Directories=actions/16,actions/22,actions/24,actions/32,actions/48,actions/64,actions/72,actions/128,animations/16,animations/22,animations/24,animations/32,animations/48,animations/64,animations/128,apps/16,apps/22,apps/24,apps/32,apps/48,apps/64,apps/112,apps/128,categories/16,categories/24,categories/32,categories/48,categories/64,categories/128,places/16,places/22,places/24,places/32,places/48,places/64,places/128,mimes/16,mimes/24,mimes/32,mimes/48,mimes/128,devices/16,devices/22,devices/24,devices/32,devices/48,devices/64,devices/128,emblems/16,emblems/22,emblems/24,emblems/32,emblems/48,emblems/64,emblems/128,status/16,status/22,status/24,status/32,status/48,status/64,status/128,stock/16,stock/22,stock/24,stock/32,stock/48,notifications/16,notifications/22,notifications/24,notifications/32,notifications/48,panel/16,panel/22,panel/24,panel/48,

[actions/16]
Size=16
Context=Actions
Type=Fixed
```

Theoreticaly, you can build your own icon-theme containing only one icon and including another icon-theme for the whole rest.

I hope this answers your question. Please excuse my poor english...

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation - I wouldn't have known to look in the hidden .icons folder. Also, your english is fantastic!